# Detail Accessory Button Segue

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4, xcode4.3

1. My app have UITableViewController and DetailViewController.
2. UITableViewController with multi cell selection and Detail accessory button.
3. If the user select multiple cell and tap on TOTAL Button Alert message show the total of courses price.
4. And if user tap on Detail accessory button it Segue to DetailViewController.

OK now my problem is how could I do that with my code:

UITableViewController.m

```
    - (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

        return cell;


    }


    - (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"courseCode"] description];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"courseName"] description];

    }

    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {

        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
        }            
    }

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{



}


    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];


        if ([[[object valueForKey:@"creditHours"] description]isEqualToString: @""]) {

        }
        //some thing doing if the user deselect the cell..



    }

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if ([[[object valueForKey:@"creditHours"] description]isEqualToString: @""]) {

        }

        //some thing doing if the user deselect the cell..

    }

    - (IBAction)doneButton:(id)sender {

        given the total...

    }
```

DetailViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *courseCodeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *courseNameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *creditHoursLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *preRequisitesLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *coursePriceLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *courseEPPLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *courseDetailLabel;
```

DetailViewController.m

```
@interface DetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize detailItem = _detailItem;
@synthesize courseCodeLabel = _courseCodeLabel;
@synthesize courseNameLabel = _courseNameLabel;
@synthesize creditHoursLabel = _creditHoursLabel;
@synthesize preRequisitesLabel = _preRequisitesLabel;
@synthesize coursePriceLabel = _coursePriceLabel;
@synthesize courseEPPLabel = _courseEPPLabel;
@synthesize courseDetailLabel = _courseDetailLabel;


#pragma mark - Managing the detail item



- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    [self configureView];

    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.courseCodeLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"courseCode"] description];
        self.courseNameLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"courseName"] description];
        self.creditHoursLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"creditHours"] description];
        self.preRequisitesLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"preRequisites"] description];
        self.coursePriceLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"coursePrice"] description];
        self.courseEPPLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"courseEPP"] description];
        self.courseDetailLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"courseDetails"] description];

    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureView];
}
```

Notice that the segue working good in the normal way.

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: when the user tap the cell he/she will navigate to the DetailView. But it is not what I want . I want only use the Detail accessory button to navigate and the cell selection to make the collocation.  Hope that clear :)

Comment: I want to use this `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` but `indexPathForSelectedRow` in the prepareForSegue stops that!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think currently your segue links a tableview cell (that prototype) with your detail controller. You can try instead link the tableview controller itself (i.e. the entire thing) with your detail controller. (just ctrl drag from the bottom of your tableview controller to do that)

Then you handle your `-prepareForSegue` method as usual, but you will need to call `-performSegue` to actually trigger the segue. Tapping on the cell will have no effect. So in your `-tableView:tableViewaccessory....` method you can call `performSegue` to do your navigation, and handle your `didSelectRow..` method as you wish.